# An open and closed ball in the discrete space

Tags: real-analysis

let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. I am trying to find what an open and closed ball looks like in the discrete space, i.e. when $d(x,y) = 0$ for $x = y$ and $1$ otherwise.

Just considering the open ball for now, the answer is this: $B(x,r) = \{x\}$ for $r \leq 1$ and $B(x,r) = X$ for $r>1$ I am not sure how they got this.

My definition of an open ball is this $B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : d(y,x) < r \}$ so for $y = x$ we have $B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : 0 < r \}$ and for $y \not = x$ $B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : 1 < r \}$ I am not sure how $\{ y \in X : 1 < r \} = X$? Any help please

Comment: Your analysis starting with "for $y=x$..." is muddled. Going back to the definition, if $r \leq 1$, then the only value of $y$ for which $d(y,x) < r \leq 1$ is $y = x$. Hence in that case $B(x,r) = \{ x \}$. If $r > 1$, then for what values of $y$ is $d(x,y) < r$? Certainly all values of $y$ for which $d(x,y) = 1$. And that's everything.

Comment: Is this from a rudin chapter 2 exercise?

Comment: @Soke yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$ and $d(x,y) = 1$ otherwise, then for $0 < r < 1$ we have 
\begin{align}
B(x,r) &= \{ y \in X \mid d(x,y) < r \} = \{x\}\,,
\end{align}
because if $y \neq x$, then $d(x,y) = 1 > r$.

Now let $r \geq 1$. Then if $y \in X$ and $y \neq x$ we have $d(x,y) = 1 \leq r$, so $y \in B(x,r)$. Also $x \in B(x,r)$, so $X \subset B(x,r)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just observe by definition that $B(x,1)$ is the set of points less than distance $1$ away from $x$.  In the discrete space on $X$, the only point $y$ satisfying $d(x,y) <1$ is $x$ itself, hence $B(x,1) = \{x\}$.  All points of $X$ are distance $1$ from every other point of $X$, thus if $r>1$ then the ball $B(x,r)$ contains everything.